# What is the definition of Infinitely Often class in complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I was reading a paper and I came across the term $L\notin i.o.Dtime(2^{n^c}/n^c)$. What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$L\in DTIME\left(2^{n^c}/n^c\right)$ if there exists a machine $M$ running in time $O\left(2^{n^c}/n^c\right)$ which correctly decides membership to $L$ for an infinite number of input lengths, i.e. for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $n\ge k$ such that $\forall x\in\{0,1\}^n : M(x)=\mathbb{1}_{x\in L}$. You can think of it as having a non trivial special case where we can decide membership to $L$ (where by non trivial I mean an infinite set of inputs, not just very short ones).

Comment: Then what is the difference between normal classes and infinitely often. Why it mentions infinitely often explicitly? Any normal class is generalized for any length input..

Comment: I didn't say all input lengths, consider the language $L=\big\{\langle M\rangle | L(M)=\Sigma^* \lor |\langle M \rangle| \text{ is odd}\big\}$ is infinitely often linear, since I can trivially handle odd length inputs, even though $L$ itself is undecidable.

Comment: Okay got it...Thanks